# I get the error: unable to read memory c#

Tags: c#

My currentfloor is -1. When i push the button to start on -1 i get the error "unable to read memory". Can anybody help me?

When i push the other buttons it works perfect.

```
    public class Lift
    {

        public event LiftActieHandler StoppendEvent;
        public event LiftActieHandler VerdiepingBereiktEvent;
        public event LiftActieHandler StartingEvent;
        public delegate void LiftActieHandler(LiftActieEventArgs e);

        private int hoogsteverdieping;  //houdt de hoogste verdieping bij
        private int laagsteverdieping;  //houdt de laagste verdieping bij
        public int HuidigeVerdieping = -1;
        private int? VolgendeVerdieping;
        public LiftDirection Richting { get; set; }
        public LiftStatus Status { get; set; } = LiftStatus.Stopped;
        private List<Request> Requests = new List<Request>();
        private Timer beweging = new Timer(4000); // 4 seconden tussen 2 //verdiepen



        public Lift(int hoogsteverdieping, int laagsteverdieping)
        {
            this.hoogsteverdieping = hoogsteverdieping;
            this.laagsteverdieping = laagsteverdieping;

            beweging.Elapsed += VerdiepingBereikt;


        }


        //public void DoeTest()
        //{
        //    // Test
        //    Requests.Add(new Request(2));
        //    Requests.Add(new Request(1));
        //    Requests.Add(new Request(0));
        //    StartLift();
        //}



        /// <summary>
        /// Voorbeeldfunctie waarmee aan het Liftsysteem kenbaar wordt gemaakt ///dat er een
        /// nieuw doel moet toegevoegd worden aan de wachtrij. Wordt aangeroepen ///door de binnenbediening.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="doelVerdieping"></param>
        public void VerdiepingAanvragen(int doelVerdieping)
        {
            Requests.Add(new Request(doelVerdieping));
            StartLift();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Voorbeeldfunctie waarmee aan het Liftsysteem kenbaar wordt gemaakt ///dat er bepaalde richting
        /// wordt aangevraagd op een verdieping. Wordt aangeroepen door de ///buitenbediening.
        /// </summary>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="aanvragendeVerdieping"></param>
        /// <param name="richting"></param>
        public void RichtingAanvragen(int aanvragendeVerdieping, LiftDirection richting)
        {
            Requests.Add(new Request(aanvragendeVerdieping, richting));
            StartLift();
        }

        private void StartLift()
        {
            if (Status == LiftStatus.Moving || Requests.Count == 0) { return; }

            BepaalVolgendeVerdieping(Richting);
            BijwerkenRichting();
            Status = LiftStatus.Moving;
            beweging.Start();
            StartingEvent(new LiftActieEventArgs(HuidigeVerdieping, Richting));
        }

        public string GeefWachtRij()
        {
            string wachtrij = "";

            foreach (Request aanvraag in Requests)
            {
                wachtrij += aanvraag.DoelVerdieping + ",";
            }

            if (wachtrij.Length > 0)
            {
                // Verwijder laatste komma uit text
                wachtrij = wachtrij.Substring(0, wachtrij.Length - 1);
            }

            return wachtrij;
        }


        private void VerdiepingBereikt(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            BijwerkenVerdieping();
            DoeVolgendeActie();
        }

        private void BijwerkenVerdieping()
        {
            // Bijwerken verdieping
            if (Richting == LiftDirection.Up)
            {
                HuidigeVerdieping += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                HuidigeVerdieping -= 1;
            }

            VerdiepingBereiktEvent(new LiftActieEventArgs(HuidigeVerdieping, Richting));
        }

        private void DoeVolgendeActie()
        {
            // Moet lift stoppen of doorgaan naar volgende verdiep
            // Stoppen indien
            // 1) Huidige verdiep gelijk is aan volgende verdiep (doel bereikt)
            // 2) Indien huidige verdiep ondertussen in Requests

            bool stop = false;
            foreach (Request aanvraag in Requests)
            {
                if (aanvraag.DoelVerdieping == HuidigeVerdieping)
                {
                    stop = true;
                    break;
                }
            }


            if (HuidigeVerdieping == VolgendeVerdieping || stop)
            {
                // Bijwerken Status
                Status = LiftStatus.Stopped;
                beweging.Stop();

                BijwerkenWachtrij();

                StoppendEvent(new LiftActieEventArgs(HuidigeVerdieping, Richting));


                // Open deuren en wacht 4 seconden
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
                StartLift();
            }
            else
            {
                BepaalVolgendeVerdieping(Richting);
            }

        }

        private void BijwerkenWachtrij()
        {
            for (int i = Requests.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (Requests[i].DoelVerdieping == HuidigeVerdieping)
                {
                    Requests.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }

        private void BepaalVolgendeVerdieping(LiftDirection richting)
        {
            VolgendeVerdieping = null;

            foreach (Request aanvraag in Requests)
            {
                if (richting == LiftDirection.Down)
                {
                    // Lift gaat naar beneden dus zoek eerst volgende verdiep //lager dan huidig verdiep
                    if (aanvraag.DoelVerdieping < HuidigeVerdieping && (VolgendeVerdieping == null || aanvraag.DoelVerdieping > VolgendeVerdieping))
                    {
                        VolgendeVerdieping = aanvraag.DoelVerdieping;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Lift gaat naar boven dus zoek eerst volgende verdiep //hoger dan huidig verdiep
                    if (aanvraag.DoelVerdieping > HuidigeVerdieping && (VolgendeVerdieping == null || aanvraag.DoelVerdieping < VolgendeVerdieping))
                    {
                        VolgendeVerdieping = aanvraag.DoelVerdieping;
                    }
                }


            }

            if (Requests.Count > 0 && !VolgendeVerdieping.HasValue)
            {
                if (richting == LiftDirection.Down)
                {
                    BepaalVolgendeVerdieping(LiftDirection.Up);
                }
                else
                {
                    BepaalVolgendeVerdieping(LiftDirection.Down);
                }

            }

        }

        private void BijwerkenRichting()
        {
            // Bijwerken richting
            if (HuidigeVerdieping < VolgendeVerdieping)
            {
                Richting = LiftDirection.Up;
            }

            if (HuidigeVerdieping > VolgendeVerdieping)
            {
                Richting = LiftDirection.Down;
            }


            // Opgooien event
            StartingEvent(new LiftActieEventArgs(Richting, Status));
        }

    }

    public class Request
    {
        public Request(int doelVerdieping, LiftDirection richting)
        {
            DoelVerdieping = doelVerdieping;
            Richting = richting;
        }

        public Request(int doelVerdieping)
        {
            DoelVerdieping = doelVerdieping;
        }

        public int DoelVerdieping { get; set; }
        public LiftDirection Richting { get; set; }
    }

}
     public class LiftActieEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int Verdieping { get; }
        public LiftDirection Richting { get; }
        public LiftStatus Status { get; }

        // Constructor
       public LiftActieEventArgs(int verdieping, LiftDirection richting)
        {
            Richting = richting;
            Verdieping = verdieping;
        }

        public LiftActieEventArgs(LiftDirection richting, LiftStatus status)
        {
            Richting = richting;
            Status = status;
        }
    }
     public enum LiftDirection
    { 
        Up = 0,
        Down = 1
    }

    public enum LiftStatus
    {
        Moving = 0,
        Stopped = 1
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Lift lift;


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //lift initializeren met max en min verdieping
            lift = new Lift(2, -1);
            lift.StoppendEvent += new Lift.LiftActieHandler(OnLiftStopped);
            lift.VerdiepingBereiktEvent += new Lift.LiftActieHandler(OnVerdiepingBereikt);
            lift.StartingEvent += new Lift.LiftActieHandler(OnLiftStarting);


            // huidige verdiep zetten
            ZetVerdieping(lift.HuidigeVerdieping);

            //lift.DoeTest();
        }

        private void btnBuitenBediening_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] parameters = ((Button)e.OriginalSource).CommandParameter.ToString().Split('#');
            int verdieping = int.Parse(parameters[0]);
            LiftDirection direction = parameters[1] == "UP" ? LiftDirection.Up : LiftDirection.Down;

            // Opvullen Queue
            lift.RichtingAanvragen(verdieping, direction);


            // Tonen wachtrij
            lblWachtrij.Content = lift.GeefWachtRij();
        }

        private void btnBinnenBediening_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int gevraagdeverdieping = int.Parse(((Button)e.OriginalSource).Content.ToString());

            // Opvullen wachtrij
            lift.VerdiepingAanvragen(gevraagdeverdieping);


            // Tonen wachtrij
            lblWachtrij.Content = lift.GeefWachtRij();
        }


        private void OnLiftStopped(LiftActieEventArgs e)
        {
            // Status bijwerken
            BijwerkenStatus();

            // Wachtrij tonen
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { lblWachtrij.Content = lift.GeefWachtRij(); }));
        }

        private void OnVerdiepingBereikt(LiftActieEventArgs e)
        {
            ZetVerdieping(e.Verdieping);
        }

        private void ZetVerdieping(int verdieping)
        {
            // Bijwerken verdieping
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { PaneelVerdieping.Text = verdieping.ToString(); }));
        }

        private void OnLiftStarting(LiftActieEventArgs e)
        {
            // Richting aangeven
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                if (e.Richting == LiftDirection.Down)
                {
                    PaneelRichting.Text = "▼";
                }
                else
                {
                    PaneelRichting.Text = "▲";
                };

                // Wachtrij tonen
                lblWachtrij.Content = lift.GeefWachtRij();
            }));

            // Status bijwerken
            BijwerkenStatus();

        }

        private void BijwerkenStatus()
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                if (lift.Status == LiftStatus.Moving)
                {
                    if (lift.Richting == LiftDirection.Down)
                    {
                        lblStatus.Content = "Naar beneden";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblStatus.Content = "Naar boven";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lblStatus.Content = "Gestopt";
                }
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "My currentfloor is -1" ? What? 1) There is not explanation of what this code does. 2) the problem description is cryptic and almost non existent. 3) the comments (the only descriptive part in your post) are not in english..... These 3 points decrease the probability of finding proper help drastically

Comment: To extend @MongZhu's comment: I can make out the code because I speak Dutch, but you can't rely on people speaking Dutch here. Either translate your variable names; provide meaningfull comments, but preferable **explain** both the intention of the code, and which part is reponsible for the fauty behavior. (Off-topic but adding to the issue: Reading through it now, your code is massively overengineered, and uses a lot of different approaches. E.g. one part uses magic numbers, another part specifically avoids using them)

Comment: Do you get an exception? If so then please post the exception type, the exact message you get and its stacktrace.

Comment: The exeption i get is the following:

Comment: Richting: unable to read memory     Status: unable to read memory   HuidigeVerdieping: unable to read memory   VolgendeVerdieping unable to read memory and i: error CS0103: the name i does not exist in the current content

Comment: @olivier: what line is the exception thrown on? You can see that in the stacktrace of the exception (or when you call `.ToString()`)

Comment: System.StackOverflowException: private void BepaalVolgendeVerdieping(LiftDirection richting)

Comment: You might be stuck in an infinite recursive call here (as you call `BepaalVolgendeVerdieping` recursively). Put breakpoints in it to see what really happens, but that's what StackOverflowException usually means

Answer (score 1):

There's a real problem in your `BepaalVolgendeVerdieping` (*findTheNextFloor*) method :

What do you expect to happen if there's only one `Request` in `Requests` and this request's `DoelVerdieping` (*target floor*) is **equal** to `HuidigeVerdieping` (*current floor*) ?

Well I'll tell you :

***Infinite recursive call !***

`VolgendeVerdieping` (*next floor*) will never have a value as all `if`s that can assign it will **never** pass, then you'll be calling recursively `BepaalVolgendeVerdieping(LiftDirection.Up);`, then `BepaalVolgendeVerdieping(LiftDirection.Down);` and this indefinitely.

---

Note that this is what I saw at first glance, so you might want to think more into it as there may be more critical cases.

---

Edit : I added translation (thank you online translators) for clarifications